# Unable to add two scopes with different range in same subnet for windows DHCP server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I am trying to add two scopes of different range say (192.168.0.5-192.168.0.10), (1952.168.0.15-192.168.0.25) on windows DHCP server while I am trying to add the second scope it says the address range and mask conflicts with the existing scope is this valid? do we need to enable any setting to support multiple scopes within the same subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single scope `192.168.0.5-192.168.0.25` and exclude `192.168.0.11-192.168.0.14` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first scope uses the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and the second scope also uses the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 then yes, the second scope would overlap the first scope. You can't "break up" a network by creating multiple overlapping scopes. If you want to create the scopes as you've described than you need to change the subnet mask.